# Dropdownlist with multiple-field key

Tags: php, yii

Is there any way I can use Yii dropDownList to make selection of objects from a table with primary key which has 4 fields? I know how to do it with 1 key field and 1 value field, but my key has 4 fields. Thanks

Comment: You would be more likely to get a useful answer if you showed some code and also an example of the data you are talking about. Otherwise this is just going to get downvotes and/or closed

Comment: Do you use yii1 or yii2 ?

Comment: I use yii1.1.13 but I can consider updating if that wouldn't change my whole app, not familiar with yii2 tho